# screw stuck in bathroom faucet

Tags: plumbing-fixture

First of all I thought replacing a bathtub faucet wouldn't be hard, I took off the old faucet and commenced to fit the new on it. I got it assembled and put the screw in and now the screw is stuck, it won't go in our out. It appears the screw was too big and too long??? How can I remove it?? thanks

Comment: Welcome to DIY.SE! Can you add a photo of your stuck screw? It would help us give you a better answer.

Comment: It's not a bad idea to start the screw threading while you have the faucet free in hand.  Can we assume it's an Allan screw, and can you confirm whether it is in straight and whether it has been stripped(The screw and or driver have damaged each other), which would mean a different set of tools are necessary?